# VSCode showing duplicate paths on the autocomplete panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently updated my VS Code, and I'm writing on TypeScript.
I have a strange behavior - I see duplicate paths on the autocomplete panel.
Anyone faced this issue before and maybe know how to fix it?
Thanks.

Technical details about my VS Code version:

Version: 1.85.1 (Universal)
Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
Date: 2023-12-13T09:48:06.308Z (5 days ago)
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.6.0

[image]

Comment: please create a minimal setup to reproduce this issue and then raise an issue ticket by using `Help > Report Issue` in the VS Code menu bar. Please ping me in your issue ticket with "@starball5", or ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.