# Vscode duplicates files. I can't connect any of the files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

Please help me solve the problem. The files are duplicated and I can't do anything. I tried creating other folders with different paths, but they still duplicate the files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtWMd.png)

There are no hidden files in the folder itself.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElDvD.png)

Here are the extensions installed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgXQG.png)

Please help, I reinstalled everything. I checked all the settings.

the same error appeared later:

```
[Info - 6:27:20 PM] ESLint server is starting.
[Info - 6:27:20 PM] ESLint server running in node v18.15.0
[Info - 6:27:20 PM] ESLint server is running.
[Warn - 6:28:12 PM] Detected package manager() differs from the one in the deprecated packageManager setting(npm). We will honor this setting until it is removed.
[object Object]
[Info - 6:28:12 PM]
Failed to load the ESLint library for the document c:\Portfolio\Calculator\index.js

To use ESLint please install eslint by running npm install eslint in the workspace folder Calculator
or globally using 'npm install -g eslint'. You need to reopen the workspace after installing eslint.

If you are using yarn or pnpm instead of npm set the setting eslint.packageManager to either yarn or pnpm
Alternatively you can disable ESLint for the workspace folder Calculator by executing the 'Disable ESLint' command.`
```

After installing ESlint into the project, the files are still duplicated

Comment: Why are you adding `../Calculator/` to everything? This is confusing to me, and maybe it's also confusing to VS Code. Do `./` instead of `../Calculator/`

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: very probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77678914/11107541